# Using __str__ for printing array elements of an object

Tags: python

I am doing a mini project in Coursera. (`Card` is another class which has been declared elsewhere.)

```
class Deck:    
    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = []
        for i in SUITS:
            for j in RANKS:
                self.deck.append(Card(str(i), str(j)))
    def deal_card(self):
        self.temp = random.randrange(0,52)        
        return(self.deck[self.temp])

    def __str__(self):
        #TODO

main()
test_deck = Deck()
c1 = test_deck.deal_card()
print test_deck
```

I understand that the list `self.deck` contains a list of Card objects, Can anyone tell me how to print the value of `self.deck` (which this object is referring to) in my `__str__` method?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific with what you expect the output string to look like. If you want the literal equivalent to calling `print(self.deck)`, simply `return str(self.deck)`. But otherwise we need to know what you want from your output formatting.

Comment: The literal answer to your question is `str(self.deck)` but I figure you're asking something more. What are you expecting as output?

Comment: As a side note, you should never use `class Deck:` in Python 2.x; always use `class Deck(object):`. Otherwise, you're creating an old-style class, which is bad. (If you want to know _why_ it's bad, you have to learn about old-style classes, and a lot of other stuff that you can probably get away with never learning before you're ready to go to Python 3.x where none of it matters anymore… but if you're curious, search the docs.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just convert it into a string.

```
return str(self.deck)
```

Comment: Strange how loads of answers for similar questions don't mention this obvious-in-hindsight solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this:

```
def __str__(self):
  return ','.join(str(x) for x in self.deck)
```

After, each of the Card instances of the deck must have their own str method overridden so that it formats properly too.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: This, is not a question, but an answer, a suggestion

Comment: Guys, I'm sorry but this is an answer. I've removed the question mark for you pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

> Python's [Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) should tell you how to use `__str__`.

Basically when you do:

```
print something
```

Python calls the `__str__` method of `something` and writes that to the output.

Based on my guess, you would probably want to print fact that this object is a deck. So something like this might be what you want:

```
class Deck:
    # ...
    def __str__(self):
        return "Deck()"
```

---

Since you are learning Python, I have a bunch of suggestions:

1. As @abarnert said, when you do `class ABC:` in Python 2, it is an old-style class. (More [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes))
2. Although not necessary, you should have a empty lines before every function.
3. Avoid using single-character variable names. (like `i` and `j`)

So, your code (should) look like:

```
class Deck(object):

    def __init__(self):  # Blank line above...
        self.deck = []
        # Change variable names...
        for suit in SUITS:
            for rank in RANKS:
                self.deck.append(Card(str(suit), str(rank)))

    def deal_card(self):  # Blank line above...
        self.temp = random.randrange(0,52)
        return(self.deck[self.temp])

    def __str__(self):
        return "Deck()"
```

And lastly, you might want to read [this](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html), which turns out to be the same page as the one I linked before, twice.